# Can you omit the "a" at any time?

Tags: grammar

> Craig is wearing fancy suit.
>
> Craig is wearing a fancy suit.

Are both ok and can you omit the "a" at any time, or you can only do it in a particular situation?

Comment: No - you *can't* omit the article in your example. But it's hard to explain exactly why, because there's normally no article in *Craig is wearing **fancy dress***, which means clothing that you wear for a party at which everyone tries to look like a famous person or a person from a story, from history, or similar. If the article was included there, as *Craig's wife is wearing **a fancy dress***, that would mean the dress Craig's wife is wearing is ***ornate, striking, highly decorative***. (I'll ignore the possibility that Craig might be a "cross-dresser"! :)

Comment: Basically, "fancy dress" is an ***idiomatic usage***, that doesn't necessarily require the same syntax as "normal" language. But "fancy suit" is just an ordinary noun preceded by an optional adjective. Without the adjectives, it's *Craig is wearing **a suit*** and *His wife is wearing **a dress*** - but for those usages, the article is always necessary regardless of whether you include an adjective or not.